# Eloquent Get Models based on fields in related tables

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have multiple Models related to my User model(eg: profiles, addresses, orders,...etc)

I want to get all the users that were updated in the past 24 hours,  based on the update_at field in each of the related tables accordingly.

I have found the following if u have one related table, but in my case I have more than 3 tables that I need to check:

```
$users = User::with('orders')
            ->where('updated_at', $valueA)
            ->whereHas('orders', function($query)
                {
                    $query->where('updated_at', $valueB);
                })->get();
```

I hope someone can help me to know how to apply this for multiple where clauses n=on multiple related tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below code,

```
$users = User::with(['profiles', 'addresses', 'orders'])
        ->whereDate('updated_at','>', $yesterdayDate)
        ->orWhereHas('orders', function($query) use ($yesterdayDate){
             $query->whereDate('updated_at','>', $yesterdayDate);
        })->orWhereHas('addresses', function($query) use ($yesterdayDate) {
             $query->where('updated_at','>', $yesterdayDate);
        })->orWhereHas('profiles', function($query) use ($yesterdayDate){
             $query->where('updated_at','>', $yesterdayDate);
        })->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have direct relation from users to all models like orders, profiles, addresses etc then you can try this.

```
         $valueA = $time // whatever time you want
         $users = User::
         where('updated_at', $valueA)
        ->whereHas('orders', function($query) use ($valueA)
            {
                $query->where('updated_at', $valueA);
            })
          with('orders')
          ->whereHas('profiles', function($query) use ($valueA)
            {
                $query->where('updated_at', $valueA);
            })
          with('profiles')
         ->whereHas('addresses', function($query) use ($valueA)
            {
                $query->where('updated_at', $valueA);
            })
          with('addresses')
          ->get();
```

Thank you.